# Matlab function dependent on time matrix

Tags: loops, matlab, time, fft, series

How could you make a function in matlab where at a desired value of time, I can tell if a function, is above or below a threshold, given the time span is very small (essentially, for t = 0:1/2000000:1/10000) while the function created is also dependent on a for loop of n increments for instance, n = 0:30 (a fourier series summation)?

The biggest problem I'm seeing is making a matrix for this function with all the time values and how a specific (very small) time input can correspond to one of the integer values of that matrix. The fourier series works well and I think it should run the fourier for loop for every T value? or correlating both loops to have the the fourier run for all time and then picking out individual time locations?

Comment: I don't think you are explaining what you want very clearly, apologies. Can you make that first paragraph a bit more clear?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], indicating the parts you need help with